# bytes, strings and urllib in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around this error.  It's really basic, but it seems to say the opposite of what is true.

```
>>> x=b'hi'
>>> urllib.parse.unquote(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/parse.py", line 609, in unquote
    if '%' not in string:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I've passed the code a `bytes` object, I would hope that's bytes-like enough.   `urllib.parse.unquote()` seems to only work with a `str` object.

So why would it generate an error saying it needs a bytes-like object?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes, which encodes its string parameter to bytes if it receives a str object.

```
urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(x)
```

Comment: It's a very useful answer for the question I didn't know I had.   Thanks for the tip.   I can't mark this the answer as I was asking why the original TypeError is so cryptic.